# Is there some way to point Visual Studio Code's class Intellisense to prebuilt jars

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, static-analysis

I am currently working on a large code base that involves automatically generated code. In the code base we use these automatically generated classes and functions. However, VS code doesn't know these classes exist yet as they haven't been built. My question is whether there is a way to compile the code, build the generated sources, and point VS code's intellisense feature to use the generated jars in order to understand that those methods do exist.

Any help (prescriptive, explanatory, or anything else) would be greatly appreciated because this stuff is way over my head.

Comment: you'll have to find a LSP plugin